# Best method for Edit Distance and LCS algorithms

Tags: string, algorithm

I'm writing a monografie for college about optimizations in Edit Distance and LCS algorithms.

Searching the internet I found two optimizations **The four Russians method** and **Ukkonen Algorithm**.

I have to test it with [this SPOJ problem](http://www.spoj.com/problems/LCS0/) (which requires a better Big O than O(NM) or O(N^2)). My question is simple:

Which is better in terms of performance?